# How to change url of Swagger SpringMVC UI

Tags: spring, swagger, swagger-ui

I use swagger-springmvc in a spring-boot project and everything works fine but when I add the swagger-spring-mvc-ui dependency to my project, swagger-ui overloads my request mapping for the base url. I'm pretty shure there's a way to point the UI to another url. Does anybody know how to change the default-path of swagger-ui?

Comment: What version of springfox are you using?

Comment: i use this one:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mangofactory/swagger-springmvc/0.8.8

Comment: Perhaps you could try the [2.0 snapshot version](https://github.com/springfox/springfox). It makes it a lot simpler by just adding the springfox-swagger-ui dependency and a @EnableSwaggerUI annotation

Answer (score 3):

You are using old version 0.8.8 which from [com.mangofactory](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mangofactory/swagger-springmvc/0.8.8)

I recommend you to use version 2.3.1 from [io.springfox](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2/2.3.1)

> Note: If you follow the tutorial you can access swagger without having to download Swagger-UI manually
>
> ```
> http://localhost:8080/your-app-root/swagger-ui.html
> ```
>
> Document Url is now available at
>
> ```
> http://localhost:8080/your-app-root/v2/api-docs
> ```
>
> You can change document url by specifying a property source in appication.properties file using
>
> ```
> springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path
> ```

[reference to the changes](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/docs/transitioning-to-v2.md)

[spring boot demo](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos)

[tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api)

Comment: i will try your answer asap and mark your answer as useful.